# In React Redux Saga api is being called multiple time in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, redux-saga

I'm facing weird behavior while fetching the records in redux saga. When I try to call an action in useeffect from the class, it is being called in loop multiple times. For that reason, there are infinite api calls.

Can anybody tell me where i'm wrong please? Following is my code.

**Reducer**

```
// @flow
import {
    FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE,
    FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE_ERROR
} from "./actionTypes";

const INIT_STATE = {
    error: null,
    isLoading: false,
    doctorProfile: {}
};

const DoctorProfileReducer = (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            };
        case FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                doctorProfile: action.payload
            };
        case FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                error: action.error
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default DoctorProfileReducer;
```

**Action**

```
import {
    FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE,
    FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE_ERROR
} from "./actionTypes";

export const fetchDoctorProfileAction= () => ({
    type: FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE
});

export const fetchDoctorProfileSuccessAction= (doctorProfile) => ({
    type: FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
    payload: doctorProfile
});

export const fetchDoctorProfileErrorAction= (error) => ({
    type: FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE_ERROR,
    error: error
});
```

**Saga**

```
import { takeEvery, fork, put, all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

// Redux States
import { FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE } from './actionTypes';
import { fetchDoctorProfileSuccessAction, fetchDoctorProfileErrorAction } from './actions';
import { fetchDoctorProfileApi } from '../../../services/doctorProfile';

import {FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE_URL} from '../../../helpers/urls';

function* fetchDoctorProfileSaga() {
    try {
        const response = yield call(fetchDoctorProfileApi,FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE_URL);
        yield put(fetchDoctorProfileSuccessAction(response));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(fetchDoctorProfileErrorAction(error));
    }
}

export function* watchFetchDoctorProfile() {
    yield takeEvery(FETCH_DOCTOR_PROFILE, fetchDoctorProfileSaga)
}

function* doctorProfileSaga() {
    yield all([
        fork(watchFetchDoctorProfile),
    ]);
}

export default doctorProfileSaga;
```

**Calling page**

```
useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchDoctorProfileAction();
        const result = props.doctorProfile;
    });

...........

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { error, doctorProfile, pending } = state.DoctorProfileReducer;
    return { error , doctorProfile, pending };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchDoctorProfileAction})(ProfessionalProfilePrimary));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add a condition in your useEffect() hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!props.doctorProfile && !props.pending) {
    props.fetchDoctorProfileAction();
  }
  
  const result = props.doctorProfile;
}, [props.doctorProfile, props.pending]);
```

**NOTE:** in your component `mapStateToProps` you have `pending` but in your store you have `isLoading`; make sure you are correctly mapping the state to the prop ;)

Comment: Still it's being called multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; the condition is wrong. You should also check that there is no pending request. I am going to update the code.

Comment: @secan : i'm using this https://cartoonmangodev.github.io/react-boilerplate-redux-saga-hoc-docs/ boiler-plate code, at here I face same issue , like multiple time api call